# Creating only several hours of a day as a time series

Tags: r, time-series

I have many zeros in my hourly time series data but for sure I know that from 22:00-7:00 the values are all 0. So, I don't want to put these in my forecasting model. Otherwise I have a very sparse dataset that I couldn't find a good model.

I want to create a time series only for the hours between 7:00 to 22:00 for each day. Can it be possible? How?

Thanks a lot.
Ceylan

Answer (score 1):

Certainly you can do that. Simply extract the periods that are "active" and encode them as a `ts` object. Just make sure to set the correct `frequency`, which in your case would be 15, since there are 15 "active" hourly buckets in every day.

When forecasting, you may want to consider models for [multiple-seasonalities](/questions/tagged/multiple-seasonalities), since you will probably have time of day and day of week seasonality. (And possibly also longer periods, like day of year.)

As an example, I create hourly data for 15 days with zeros in 9 out of 24 hours below, then plot it, then extract the "active" hours, turn these into a `ts` object, and finally fit a very simple `ets()` model.

```
n_days <- 21
set.seed(1)
all_data <- cbind(matrix(0,nrow=n_days,ncol=7),
    matrix(rnorm(n_days*15,20,5),nrow=n_days),
    matrix(0,nrow=n_days,ncol=2))
dimnames(all_data) <- list(paste0("day_",sprintf("%02i",1:n_days)),paste0("hour_",sprintf("%02i",0:23)))
all_data

plot(as.vector(t(all_data)),type="o",pch=19,xlab="Hour",ylab="",las=1)
abline(v=24*(1:n_days),lty=2)

data_without_zeros <- all_data[,8:22]
data_without_zeros_ts <- ts(as.vector(t(data_without_zeros)),frequency=15)

library(forecast)
ets(data_without_zeros_ts)
```

[image: time series]

Comment: Thank you very much Stephan. This is very helpful. Actually, there are more zeros in my data but 22:00-7:00 definitely zero part. This solution helps me a lot. I appreciate it. Have a wonderful day.

Comment: There are different "kinds" of zeros. For instance, a supermarket may be closed between 2200 and 0700, so zero sales in this period represent the *impossibility* of shopping, and these periods should be treated in a way similar to what I did here. Conversely, you might also have zero sales, say, between 0900 and 1000, simply because there was zero demand. This zero demand should of course be included in your model, because it is *valid*.